# Dock auto-hide not working on Desktop Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: 20.04

I have the dock auto-hide feature enabled, which works as expected except when I'm on the Desktop. There, it won't hide. It's pretty annoying considering I have files I want to see and interact with, which are being partially hidden by the dock...

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: As the message under "Auto-Hide the Dock" states: *The Dock hides when any windows overlap with it*. If there is nothing using the same screen area, the dock will be visible 

Comment: @Matigo Although you're right, I somehow expected it to behave the same way it did on Ubuntu 16. I really don't understand the purpose of changing this. Thanks for noticing, anyway!

Comment: @89f3a1c "I really don't understand the purpose of changing this." 16.04 by default had shipped with the Unity desktop, Canonical's in-house-developed desktop environment. Sometime after 16.04 however Canonical announced abandoning the Unity effort, and started shipping newer versions equipped with the independently developed Gnome desktop, which is a pretty different beast. So some of the changes you encounter might not have been implemented on purpose; rather, they just so "happened" through the switching of desktop providers, I believe...

Comment: @Levente I was aware of the change from Unity to Gnome, though again I've not had it present, so thanks for bringing it up! It seemed strange to me to let items on the desktop be hidden by the dock anyway, so I initially thought I was missing something, and not that they missed it. But hey, problem solved, luckily!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get finer-grain control over how the dock behaves via the `gsettings` API.

If you wish to deal with these settings via a graphical user interface, then you can install the dconf-editor app:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Open it and navigate to the `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock` schema, or, for a similar effect use the search button and search for "dash-to-dock".

You will be presented with a number of settings (presented in alphabetical order).

The most interesting ones for your case are quoted below.

I believe that I have the dock set up to behave in a similar way that you are aiming for — it shows up *only* when I move my mouse cursor to the left edge of the screen — so I also share my settings:

---

> **autohide**
> *Dock shown on mouse over*

I have this enabled ^^

---

> **dock-fixed**
> *Dock always visible*

I have this disabled ^^

---

> **intellihide**
> *Dock dodges windows*

I have this disabled ^^ (I think this is the most significant one impacting the behavior in question.) (By default, it was enabled.)

---

> **pressure-threshold**

I have this ^^ set to `50`

---

> **require-pressure-to-show**
> *Require pressure to show the dash*

I have this enabled ^^

Comment: After installing unable to see it in the search.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @Levente is correct.  If you'd like to use the command-line to adjust the appropriate setting, without having to install `dconf-editor`, simply run the following:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide false`

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the **Dodge windows** setting

[image: dialog with toggle and options]